# Persistently Store visited link so as not to visit tomorrow

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy. I would like to know how I can save visited links persistently. I mean save links visited today so as not to visit them tomorrow.

#### What I Am Thinking

I am toying with the thought of saving each visited link to a CSV file and check it before crawling any link.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest, another great option for this is to use permanent static cache which can be configured on scrapy using these settings:

```
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True
HTTPCACHE_POLICY='scrapy.extensions.httpcache.DummyPolicy'
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS=0 # 0 instructs for cache to never expire
```

By doing it this way it allows you to debug spiders easily and to re-scrape items without re-downloading the pages in case you modify your page parsers or item schemas in any way.

Here is if you end up maintaining a csv file anyway, official python doc have good examples:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am strongly considering using HTTPCACHE. Given that this is the first time i am relating with such knowledge i will like u to to indulge in pointing to how include the 3 lines of code u offered in my scrapy project and how to subsequently search  the cached data.

Comment: Glad to help. There are several places where you can specify the settings (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) but the most common one is the `settings.py` file inside your scrapy project. As for searching inside the cache, you usually don't explicitly do that yourself, you just yield requests normally and scrapy will lookup cached responses (by your request url, method and body) and return them as if they were just downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it out of the box by setting up a job directory in which crawl state will be persisted (scheduled requests, already visited requests...). See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html.